# CASE Statement Workaround to Set Values within a Group of IDs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data in a GamePlayers Table:

```
GameId   PlayerId  BotId           
1        100       NULL
1        200       NULL
2        100       NULL
2        NULL      NULL
3        200       NULL
3        NULL      100
```

I'd like to report the percentage of Human/Computer/Bot games played. Computer and Bot games are treated separately. If I were to put this into a CASE statement it'd be a simple

```
CASE  WHEN PlayerId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Human'
      WHEN PlayerId IS NULL AND BotId IS NULL THEN 'Computer'
      WHEN PlayerId IS NULL AND BotId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Bot'
      END OpponentType
```

But of course I need to group the data by GameId in order to remove duplicate GameId.

A Computer and Bot can never play against each other. A Human can challenge a Human, but if he gets no reply after 30 seconds he is offered to play against a Bot. A human can also choose to play against the Computer separately.

What I need to do is set a value to a group of either 'Human', 'Bot' or 'Computer', then report it on Power BI. How do I group the data to find out whether a Human opponent played against either a Human, a Bot or the Computer?

This is my expected Result set:

```
GameId   GameType         
1        Human
2        Computer
3        Bot
```

Comment: Your result has to be 2 and 3 GameId?

Comment: Can you add your expected resultset?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy Apologies, just added

Comment: How do you decide which row to consider?

Comment: @Raj This is the issue I'm having, I'm unsure how to prioritize Computer/Bot over Human games

Comment: As per your statement how GameId 1 is in your output "whether a Human opponent played against either a Bot or the Computer?"

Comment: What happens if you have data with computer Vs Bot?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy Added human to group expectation. A Computer and Bot can never play against each other. A Human can challenge a Human, but if he gets no reply after 30 seconds he is offered to play against a Bot. A Human can also to play against the Computer separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use case in your group by query like below

```
 select 
       gameId, 
       case 
          WHEN count(PlayerId)=2 THEN N'Human'
          WHEN count(BotId) =1 THEN N'Bot'
          WHEN count(BotId) =0 AND count(PlayerId)=1 THEN 'Computer'
          END as OpponentType
    from GamePlayers  group by GameId
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I prefer the simplicity of this one compared to @KannanKandasamy answer, but his works too

Comment: @Powellellogram Glad that my answer was useful.

Answer (score 1):

I used your query as below:

```
Select GameId, 
    case when max(OpponentType) = mIn(opponenttype) and Min(opponenttype) = 'Human' then 'Human' 
        when min(opponenttype) = 'Computer' then 'Computer'
        when min(opponenttype) = 'Bot' then 'Bot' else null end as OpponentType 
    from ( Select GameId , CASE  WHEN PlayerId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Human'
  WHEN PlayerId IS NULL AND BotId IS NULL THEN 'Computer'
  WHEN PlayerId IS NULL AND BotId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Bot'
  END OpponentType
  from #Game ) a
group by gameid
```

You do not require to do opponenttype in subquery instead you can do this in the main query itself